# How Does salesforce stores passwords ? which algorithm / mechanism uses saelsforce to store password?

Tags: encryption, passwords

Our possible new customer asks if salesforce uses any strong algorithm encryption for user credentials.

Somebody knows how salesforce stores passwords? Any documentation? I have found nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: The answer is YES. But I don't think SFDC will be too forthcoming on the actual algorithm for security reasons and instead will simply say that it complies with X, Y and Z security standard. I am sure other are more knowledgeable about this here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose one of these https://trust.salesforce.com/en/compliance/ would cover your requirement at least from business perspective (i.e. without disclosing technical details)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe any organization that follows data security standards is storing or should be storing user passwords in any form - plain text or encrypted. Password validation can be done by using stored MD5 hashes of the password.